# Side-loaded addin is blocked

Tags: excel, security, add-in, excel-2016

Our sideloaded add-in is blocked by some regulations for one of our clients. Although the installer is signed with an EV CodeSigning certificate after installation, when the user attempts to insert the add-in he gets the following error in place of the
[image]

"To help protect your security your web browser has blocked this website from displaying non-secure content. Click here for options..."

we have tried to fix it by checking the trusted catalogs but it seems all is OK there:
[image]

the issue is under Office 16 MSO:
[image]

Any idea on what is blocking the add-in and how to release it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like Internet Explorer warning. This is usually fixed by adding the site to the "trusted sites"

Comment: @Nikolay Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it did not help, the issue is still there even after adding the site to Trusted Sites.